# project was working fine, but for no reason i start getting this error Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: getFirestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase

my project uses firebase for backend this is this config file

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  stuff ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

tried to use as to rename the function

```
import { getFirestore as getFirestoreFunction } from "firebase/firestore";
```

> worked for getFirestore

> Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: initializeApp

> tried to do the same for initializeApp

```
import { initializeApp as initFirebaseApp } from "firebase/app";
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: initializeApp

here is the version  "firebase": "^8.6.8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are running an outdated version of firebase. Installing the latest version should ideally solve the problem you're facing. You can follow the comments on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70164464/19119712

Let me know if it worked if/when you make the change. Good luck!

Comment: yep that was it, i uninstalled/reinstalled firebase now im running on     "firebase": "^10.0.0" im not sure if there are any changes in terms of function Callouts but so far everything works

Comment: That's great news!